# How do I get *the* PyObject* associated with the C++ object in SWIG?

Tags: c++, python, swig

I am able to use SWIG_NewPointerObj to pass a C++ object to Python, but it's not *the* PyObject* so I can't use it properly in Python.

**My question is**: Is there a way to fetch *the* PyObject* of a C++ object that was created from Python, in C++?

Comment: What is the signature of the C++ member function you're trying to make available in Python? And how do you intend to call it from Python?

Comment: In my case, I want to get the Python instance of a C++ struct instance.  I have multiple windows and 1 global callback for window events.  So if I create 3 windows (from Python) then I want the callback to provide one of the same 3 windows I created above.  Right now it's creating a new PyObject* so it can't be matched with the three windows created from Python, as it is a different PyObject*.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to have /the/ Python wrapper object. I think from C++ you should either only manipulate C++ members, or write python-aware C++ code. With python-aware C++ code I mean methods that take or return some arguments as PyObject* and use Python/C API calls like PyObject_CallMethod().

Comment: I want to have /the/ Python wrapper object so I know, from my Python callback def, which window the event happened on.  If the callback, in Python, gives a different object than one of the ones I created above (in my Python script), then there's no way for me, in my Python def, to know which window the event happened on.  I would have to assign IDs to windows as they're created, but I would rather not have to do that.

Comment: I avoided this by setting the callbacks through the window object, but the question is still open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a unique `PyObject` per C++ object. For example if you wrap the following:

```
struct foo {};

struct foo *test() {
  static struct foo inst;
  return &inst;
}
```

Every call to `test()` inside Python will return a new `PyObject` - SWIG has no easy way to know they're identical.

The `PyObject`s that get returned are thin wrappers, i.e. proxies around the C++ object that have no local state. From the Python perspective these all look and behave like the same object because they delegate everything to the C++ object.

If you want to get hold of *a* `PyObject` there are ways you can do this, but in general it's not a good idea because any changes you make to that object won't be visible from other `PyObject`s even if they refer to the same C++ object.